# Operations on functions reversed?

Tags: calculus

I know how to add, subtract, multiply, and divide functions but what if we were given a set of functions (say 3 of them labeled as $a(x)$, $b(x)$, and $c(x)$) and were presented with another function $d(x)$ and were asked to find what operation were used with functions $a, b, c$ to produce $d(x)$ how do you find out?
Is it a matter of trial and error ?

$$a(x) = 3x - 5$$

$$b(x) = 5x + 4$$

$$c(x) = 2x + 8$$

$$d(x) = x - 13 $$

through trial and error, I can conclude that $d(x)$ is the difference of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ but it gets confusing along the line because we have 3 variables to begin with.

Comment: is function composition allowed? like can i say f(g(x))?

Comment: No, we're only dealing with the arithmetic operations on functions (+, -, *, /). We're actually done with composition and decomposition which was way easier :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, I'm going to assume that the functions are composed from simpler basis functions, as when viewing a function space as a vector space. In your case it seems any two of your example functions can be treated as the basis pair, and you can determine the coefficients by using an appropriate scalar product.

In a more general case this is a very hard problem, with probably no general solution. My suggestion is to try to notice properties of the given functions to try to reduce the problem to one in a vector space, or other space which you are familiar with, to make the problem tractable.